# inject a view in another view that has been already loaded in asp.net mvc 6?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

someone need help here :( !!

I have a bloc of authantification html code and a btn for login and another for register. These two buttons are in all pages but I don't want my authantification code to be loaded in every pages (Render***() in _Layout.cshtml). I want to inject this bloc code in the page on login or register btn clicked.

exp: client want to register after visited pageTwo (the authantification html code is not loaded yet), and then he press the register btn => at this time the authantification html code is loaded (injected) without loading the entire pageTwo.

My authantification html is a modal, just to give you an idea:

```
<div class="modal" style="z-index:10000"> ... </div>
```

My queation: how can I inject a view(html) in the view that has been already loaded by pressing on a button ?

Thanks for helping if it's not clear let me know, and sorry for the bad english :(

**UPDATE**

Is it possible without server side manipulation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want server-side code, you need client-side code.

When button is clicked, use javascript to load html (with markup of login form only) from server, insert it into your current page (into model dialog for example) and then show that form/dialog.

`jQuery` will help you with html manipulation and when communicating with server, later you can switch to vanilla.js for less javascript libs in dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dmitry, I think your right. In my problem I need to make another http request this is why server side or client side it's a must ! Ok now I can figure out a better solution... Great thanks again !